# 1px wide diagonal stripes with gap between in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am tried to do something in CSS, but I failed miserably.
This is what I got so far:

```css
#stripes {
  height:90vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, black 50%, black 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size:4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stripes"></div>
```

As you can see, the "black-white-ratio" is always the same. So you got a 1px stripe, then a 1px gap, 1px stripe, 1px gap,...
But what I am trying to achieve, is that there are like 5px space between the stripes.
I tried changing the percentages, but that doesn't result in what I try to do either.
I'm sure this is possible somehow. Does anyone know how? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just google for `background patterns css`, there are a ton of examples.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D my eyes are now bleeding

Comment: @Paulie_D No, your codepen is literally the same of what I tried already, just bigger. I try to get a bigger gap between the lines. So like: 1px stripe, 5px gap, 1px stripe, ...

Comment: For perfect results, i would suggest svg http://www.svgeneration.com/recipes/Diagonal-Stripes/

Comment: @Kiwad I havent got alot of experience with SVG. Is SVG repeatable?

Comment: @tobias-glaus, in the link i gave you, it does what you're looking for and it gives you the code. They make it repeatable indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using `repeating-linear-gradient`

```css
#stripes {
  height: 100vh;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, /* gap */
  black 6px, /* overall width incluing gap */
  black 6px);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="stripes"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, kinda. Thanks! Adjusted it to 'linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 46%, #000 49%, #000 51%, transparent 55%)' . That's right what I need :) Thanks you!

Comment: OK, but with mine you don't need background-sizing,

Comment: True. Yours looks nice tho. Maybe gonna use that instead of mine